# "Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");"can not work

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, mariadb

i work on ubuntu with java EE-Eclipse ,tomcat and mariadb.i have written a test class and when i run as java application,it can connect to mariadb.but when i test in servlet and run on tomcat server,this line "Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");"dosen't work...i don't know why and can not solve this problem.help!help!

Comment: Are you getting a `ClassNotFoundException`? Do you know what that is? Have you started by looking it up?

Comment: What doesn't work? Exceptions? the computer starts heating and put the whole building into flames?

Comment: Maybe Tomcat doesn't have that jar. If the jar doesn't get exported to Tomcat with the jar and Tomcat doesn't already have the jar, it won't work.

Comment: @RogielSulzbach I hate that [assembly instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the driver jar to `WEB-INF/lib` in your Tomcat application / war file.

Comment: thanks!i  have thought of it yet,but i couldn't copy the jar to WEB-INF/lib in the eclipse,it raise an error.while i can copy it in the file system.